# R apply() function returning list of multiple elements

Tags: r, apply

Here is my input data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(Col1=c("A","BCCC","DE"), Col2=c("Z","BC", "DEEEE"))
test
  Col1  Col2
1    A     Z
2 BCCC    BC
3   DE DEEEE
```

I am trying to create 2 more columns in my data frame, in a way that if the string in `Col1` is contained in the string in `Col2` (or the opposite), I trim all the common characters from these 2 strings and output the 2 trimmed strings in separate columns called `Col1_short` and `Col2_short` (or dots if no match):

```
  Col1  Col2 Col1_short Col2_short
1    A     Z          .          .
2 BCCC    BC        BCC          B
3   DE DEEEE          D       DEEE
```

I am trying this kind of approach where I create a list of lists that I could further unlist and append to the original data frame, but it does not work.
Does someone could see a fix or a simpler way to do it?

My code:

```
out <- apply(
    test,
    1,
    function(x){
        ifelse(
            grepl(test$Col1, test$Col2) || grepl(test$Col2, test$Col1),
            {
                common <- ifelse(
                    nchar(test$Col1) < nchar(test$Col2),
                    nchar(test$Col1) - 1,
                    nchar(test$Col2) - 1
                )

                pattern = paste0(".{", common, "}$")

                return(
                    list(
                        Col1_short=gsub(pattern, "", x[1]),
                        Col2_short=gsub(pattern, "", x[2])
                    )
                )
            },
            return(
                list(
                    Col1_short=".",
                    Col2_short="."
                )
            )
        )
        }
    )
```

Output:

```
out
[[1]]
[[1]]$Col1_short
[1] "."

[[1]]$Col2_short
[1] "."


[[2]]
[[2]]$Col1_short
[1] "."

[[2]]$Col2_short
[1] "."


[[3]]
[[3]]$Col1_short
[1] "."

[[3]]$Col2_short
[1] "."
```

I thought to append 2 new columns to the data frame by doing:

```
test$Col1_short <- unlist(out)[attr(unlist(out), "names") == "Col1_short"]
test$Col2_short <- unlist(out)[attr(unlist(out), "names") == "Col2_short"]
```

Comment: Maybe `grepl` is not vectorizable the way you want it?

Comment: How do you create 2 new columns? Why the output is "BCC" and "B" for 2nd row and same for 3rd row?

Comment: @Ronak Shah, I added a code to create the 2 new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` and test for `Col1` and corresponding `Col2` value.

```
test[c("Col1_short", "Col2_short")] <- t(mapply(function(x, y) {
    if(grepl(x, y))
       c(substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 1), substr(y, 1, nchar(y) - 1))
    else if(grepl(y, x))
        c(substr(x, 1, nchar(x) - 1), substr(y, 1, nchar(y) - 1))
    else
        c('.', '.')
}, test$Col1, test$Col2))

test
#  Col1  Col2 Col1_short Col2_short
#1    A     Z          .          .
#2 BCCC    BC        BCC          B
#3   DE DEEEE          D       DEEE
```

**data**

Using  `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to have character columns instead of factors.

```
test <- data.frame(Col1=c("A","BCCC","DE"), Col2=c("Z","BC", "DEEEE"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below

```
dfout <-
  cbind(test, `colnames<-`(sapply(test, function(x) {
    z <-
      as.character(x)
    substring(z, 1, nchar(z) - 1)
  }), paste0(names(test), "_short")))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Col1  Col2 Col1_short Col2_short
1    A     Z                      
2 BCCC    BC        BCC          B
3   DE DEEEE          D       DEEE
```

Comment: Your code seems to just drop one character from the strings. I thought they need to be compared.

Comment: @zelite, true they need to be compared. However, with my example it works.